# ASP.Net MVC Preventing direct access to action out of RedirectToAction method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My site aims to upload files to sharepoint folders. Users are coming from another system by using a button referencing my site and contains userId and other parameters. When a call comes to my site shown below

`http://myapplication/Upload/ToFolder?entityName=new_policy&entityGuid=4451E282-80B0-E611-80E8-C4346BACFC18&systemUserId=1ADEC6E1-008C-430D-A163-D7BA7AD75689`

I authenticate user with userId and redirect user to `http://myapplication/Policy` using RedirectToAction method and setting some parameters to static properties. Because of static properties I use my params but I dont want to do this way. I want to detect that when users types directly `http://myapplication/Policy` link and throw an error like "You should come from this site only via link on other system."

How can I detect this behaviour of users ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a `tempdata` value in the first `action`...

```
TempData["isRedirect"] = true;
```

which gets read by the second `action`

```
if(TempData["isRedirect"] == null)
{
    //Deny access
}

//Set temp data again so that user can refresh
TempData["isRedirect"] = true;
```

Comment: will TempData be null when user refresh site ?

Comment: I see what you mean, you could set it when the action is invoked which would allow refresh

Comment: I realised that my application is coming to Index action 5 times :S I only do 1 redirect. Why are there so many redirects?

Comment: Add breakpoints and debug your code is the only advice I can give without seeing the code.

Comment: I added breakpoints and saw that when I add layout to my view, index action is called more than once. This is my layouts html https://jsfiddle.net/v1btp7st/ .

Comment: I realised that jquery.ui.widget.js causes multiple redirects. Do you know anything about this problem ?

Comment: @YusufDuyar I don't think I've used that library before I'm afraid.